# Magento 2 - Product Landing Page

Tags: magento2

New to Magento, and reading the documentation, but I am trying to start  off with a simple landing page for a new product. I could easily make this thing in html/css/js in a matter of hours, but I am completely lost as to what approach to take with Magento.

Should I be overriding a template? Inheritting from a theme and then creating files that will extend some layout? Should I be editing phtml files to do this?

I know the visual that I am trying to execute, and aside from a contact us about the product form there is nothing about the page that needs to be tied into the backend even.

I noticed you can input HTML into the content field. Is this an antipattern? I would really appreciate even a tiny answer saying: 'try reading about this.' or 'Oh, you might just need to create a blank template and then add some static files', etc.

**Edit here's what I've done so far (and it seems to be working):**

**1)** created a new page under content > pages.

**2)** created a new storefront theme (following these frontend developer guide [instructions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)) extending Magento Blank (seems Blank is important, couldn't just extend Luma for some reason)

**3)** to get the html content that I wanted, I went to content > pages and clicked `edit` on the page I had created. I then went to content, selected the HTML format (little button on the toolbar) and pasted in my HTML content.

**4)** In order to get my custom styles to apply, I had to extend the default_head_blocks.xml file:

```
app/design/frontend/<company>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="css/usfrienbr.css"/>
  </head>
</page>
```

Don't forget to apply your custom theme to the page!

What do you Magento veterans think? Is this an antipattern? Would there have been a better way to create this landing page?